# Problem 8.13, SET THEORY, by Thomas Jech

Tags: set-theory, cardinals

I need a hint to Exercise 8.13, *Set Theory*, Third Millennium Edition by Thomas Jech. The problem is to prove that
$ o\left({E_{\lambda_\alpha}^\kappa}\right) = \alpha $  . It seems to me that the essence is to prove that there can be no stationary set between $E_{\lambda_\alpha}^\kappa$ and $E_{\lambda_{\alpha+1}}^\kappa$.
In Chapter 8, Jech introduces the concept of *stationary* set and a well-ordering < on them. If $X$ and $Y$ are stationary sets of the cardinal $\kappa$, then $X<Y$ if the set of $\alpha\in Y$ such that $\alpha \cap X$ is NOT stationary in $\alpha$ is a non-stationary set.

Then, one defines $o\left( X \right)=\sup \{o\left( A \right)+1:A<X\}$

Finally, if $\kappa$ is a regular cardinal and $\lambda<\kappa$, then
$E_\lambda^\kappa=\{\alpha<\kappa:cf\left(\alpha\right)=\lambda\}$ and $\{\lambda_\alpha:\alpha<\kappa\}$ is the increasing sequence of cardinals less than $\kappa$.

Comment: You should explain the meanings of the symbols. What is $o$, what is $E^\kappa_{\lambda}$? What is $\lambda_\alpha$?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Some comments, firstly $<$ is not a well-ordering. It is a well-founded relation, but it isn't claimed to be linear. Secondly, you want to specify that $\lambda_\alpha$ is not "the increasing sequence of cardinals", but rather the *regular* cardinals. Moreover, that sequence has length $\kappa$ if and only if $\kappa$ is an inaccessible cardinal, which isn't necessarily the case. Now, try playing with this concept a bit with the first couple of regular cardinals, what can you say about $E^\kappa_\omega$ and $E^\kappa_{\omega_1}$?

Comment: Thanks to Asaf Karagila for your expository corrections and hint.